# Свойства текста через JS

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать, чтобы JS определял отдельное предложение, например: "Поддерживаемые браузеры", и окрашивал его в белый.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример замены текста в строке, обратите внимание, что script должен быть после html, т.к. в примере не добавлено ожидание загрузки страницы

```html
<p id="str">
Яблоки круглые и яблоки сочные.
</p>
```

```js
var re = /яблоки/gi;
var str = document.getElementById('str').innerText;
var newstr = str.replace(re, '<span class="white"> апельсины </span>');
document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = newstr;
console.log(newstr); // апельсины круглые и апельсины сочные.
```

```css
.white{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Более подробно почитать о str.replace вы можете тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace