# JS: обернуть текст в параграфе тегом strong

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Не могу понять как  на чистом JS обернуть текст в параграфе тегом strong не использую сторонних библиотек типа jQuery.

Я пробовал написать код сам но столкнулся с проблемой. Тег добавляться но он не оборачивает текст который находиться в параграфе.

Получается вот так:

```
<p>
<strong></strong>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum minima corrupti natus?
</p>
```

Вот ссылка на песочницу где я начал писать это дело.

https://jsfiddle.net/ud8rc0o3/

Comment: Вот здесь такой же ответ.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714093/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-js

Comment: Сложный, но **правильный** способ - создать тег `<strong>`, скопировать в него все потомки `<p>`, удалить все потомки `<p>`, добавить `<strong>` в `<p>`. Примерно так, насколько я знаю, работает [.wrap() в jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Я смог найти ответ на свой вопрос тут (спасибо Faris Rayhan за подробное объяснение)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079598/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-appendchild-on-node-parameter-1-is-no?newreg=22c579766d9646e88bc3de00fac7d5fb